# $ T = S + W$ is a Fredholm operator of index zero.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

**Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. A bounded linear operator $T:X \to Y$ is a Fredholm operator if $\text{KerT}$ and $Y/T(X)$ are finite dimensional. We define the index of $T$ as the difference of dimensions:
$$
\operatorname{ind}T = \text{dim}(\ker T)-\dim \left(Y/T(X)\right).
$$**

> Consider $T = S + W$, where $S$ is an isomorphism and $W$ is compact. Then $T$ is a Fredholm operator and the index of $T$ is zero. Why?

Comment: @AnneBauval Woman, could you help me? I'm lost on this question.

Comment: @Anne Bauval. I know T = I + K is a fredholm operator. Why T = S + K is a fradhom operator?

Comment: Because $\ker(S+K)=\ker((I+KS^{-1})S)=S^{-1}(\ker(I+KS^{-1}))$ and $Y/((S+K)(X))=S(X)/S((I+S^{-1}K)(X))\simeq X/((I+S^{-1}K)(X)).$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank very much. Just more question. Why $\text{ind}(S+W) = \text{ind}(S)$? Suggestion: If you want to put the answers in the comment as an answer, it will be an honor to put it as best answer.